# omxplayer on different screen

Tags: video, raspberry-pi

I'd like to have two instnces of omxplayer and switch between them.

I'm using raspian on raspberry pi.

I've tried opening one instance in one screen, and then press alt+ctrl+f2 to switch to the screen two and open the other instance of omxplayer but the video of the first screen is in overlay also in the screen called with f2 (and also all other screen I have).

Why? Is it possible to have 2 instances of omxplayer, or one instance with 2 layers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these issues ([#27- Size and Offset](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/27) & [#35 - Allow multiple instances of omxplayer running](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/35)) on the [omxplayer developers website](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer).

It would seem that this feature is actively being developed. You might have some luck by downloading the latest development release and referring to those 2 thread, specifically #27. There is a lot of info in there on how to make the newer version of `omxplayer` work with this feature enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully run several instances of OMXPlayer on Raspbian using pyomxplayer library. See code here: http://www.sundh.com/blog/2013/10/loop-videos-seamlessly-omxplayer/